# sorting data in VBA

Tags: vba, sorting, range

I am running a financial monte carlo, and as the last step I would like to sort the stored output results.  I have a sheet that contains all of the simulated results in cell D21:BM## where ##=number of simulations+20. In the rows above 21, I have various stats, (min, max, std dev, etc).

Each time I run this, it is sorting both the output lines and the lines above it.  I.e. it is not sorting my named range. 
Here is my code: (Note "Counter" is named earlier in my code as an integer and is the number of iterations that have been run.

```
Worksheets("Sand Price").Activate
Dim SortRange As Range
Set SortRange = Worksheets("Sand Price").Range("D21:BM21").Resize(Counter, 62)
SortRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 20

Range("SortRange").Sort Key1:=Range("SortRange"), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

What is frustrating is that I have added the Interior.ColorIndex command to track what is happening.  Only my output lines are being color, so in that step it is picking up the correct range.  But in the next step it is not limiting to SortRange.Note,  I have added ".cells(1,1) after "Key1:=range("SortRange")" and that did not do the trick either.

Comment: What does the named range "SortRange" point to?

Comment: Maybe you mean `SortRange.Sort Key1:=SortRange.Cells(1)` ?

Comment: I have tried Cells (1,1), Cells(1,0), Cells(0,1), Cells(0,0), and at your suggestion Cells(1), none of them worked, sadly

Comment: I have solved it myself:
Range("D21:BM21").Resize(Counter, 62).Sort Key1:=Range("SortRange").Cells(0,0), _
Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
So, for whatever reason, SortRange works for setting Key1, for setting the colored area, but not for setting to sort range, for some reason.  

while I have it working, I would still love to know why SortRange doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you need because I do not understand what you are trying to achieve based on what you are saying.  Although your `SortRange` is set horizontally on your calculated row `D21` on left to `BM21` on right if that is what they are.  You are saying your named range is `D21` to `BM21` and it is sorting but then say it is not sorting?  If that is the case then what is your named range? **D1:BM21** and ***NOT* D21:BM21**?

**D1 to BM1 [Names of Columns]**

**D2 to BM2 values**

**... (D3 - D19 to BM3 - BM19) values**

**D20 to BM20 values**

**D21 to BM21 ~totals / output / your Named Range**

Named Range = `Set SortRange = Worksheets("Sand Price").Range("D21:BM21").Resize(Counter, 62)`

```
Worksheets("[Sand Price]").Activate
Dim SortRange As Range

Set SortRange = Worksheets("[Sand Price]").Range("D1:BM21").Resize(Counter, 62)
SortRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 20

Range("SortRange").Sort key1:=Range("SortRange"), _
order1:=xlAscending, header:=xlNo
```

Added brackets to worksheet name `[Sand Price]` because of name space. Changed `D21:BM21` to `D1:BM21`.  Changed upper to lower case on the first letters for `Key` to `key`, `Order` to `order`, and `Header` to `header`.

Something else to look at is changing `Range("SortRange").Sort` to `Columns("SortRange").Sort` (or what *Mr Williams* pointed out) because the way you have it appears to be calling itself (which is a row) on itself since you declared `Dim SortRange As Range` then are trying to do `Range("SortRange")` which is equivalent to saying `SortRange("SortRange")` unless I have interpreted this wrong?

Comment: Sorry I was not more clear.  I am running simulations.  The results each simulation will be copied into this sheet (Sand Price) from other locations.  The first simulation will populate range D21:BM21, the second will go into D22:BM22, and so on until the 1,000th will populate D1021:BM1021.  I then want to sort all of the data, by row, using the information in the first column.  "Counter" is an integer that starts at zero, and with ever iteration of the simulation, it increases by 1.  So, with a 1,000 iteration simulation by the end "Counter"=zero.

Comment: So, my named range "SortRange" is meant, in this example, to go from D1021:BM1021.  If it had been a 500 iteration simulation, it will be D521:BM521.  I want to sort this range.  When I run, it seems to be sorting the range D7:BM1021 (in the 1000 iteration example).  Again, I know the named range is correct, because when I color the named range, that is working correctly.  It must be the Sort, but I have been through 100 message boards and can't see the mistake.

Comment: Your change "Changed D21:BM21 to D1:BM21" is not correct.  I honestly really want to start in D21 on the farthest left and highest corner.  Not D1.  Would it work to sort "Columns" rather than "Range"?  The area I want to sort is not the only information on the sheet.  The area D1:BM20 is all populated and NOT meant to be sorted.  Finally, I believe you are incorrect that SortRange is a row.  Again, as stated previously, I am using the Interior.ColorIndex function on SortRange, and it is definitely coloring the correct range, which in a 100 iteration simulation SortRange will be D21:BM121